# Alternatives to nested numpy.where for multiconditional pandas operations?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame with conditional column A and numeric column B.

```
    A    B
1 'foo' 1.2
2 'bar' 1.3
3 'foo' 2.2
```

I also have a Python dictionary that defines ranges of B which denote "success" given each value of A.

```
mydict = {'foo': [1, 2], 'bar': [2, 3]}
```

I want to make a new column, 'error', in the dataframe. It should describe how far outside of the acceptable bounds for A the value of B falls. If A is within the range, the value should be zero.

```
    A    B   error
1 'foo' 1.2   0
2 'bar' 1.3  -0.7
3 'foo' 2.2   0.2
```

I'm not a complete Pandas/Numpy newbie, and I'm halfway decent at Python, but this proved somewhat difficult. I don't want to do it with iterrows(), since I understand that's computationally expensive and this is going to get called a lot.

I eventually figured out a solution by combining lambda functions, pandas.DataFrame.map(), and nested numpy.where()s with given values for the optional x and y inputs.

```
getmin = lambda x: mydict[x][0]
getmax = lambda x: mydict[x][1] 
df['error'] = np.where(df.B < dtfr.A.map(getmin),
                       df.B - df.A.map(getmin),
                       np.where(df.B > df.A.map(getmax),
                                df.B - df.A.map(getmax),
                                0
                                )
                       )
```

It works, but this can't possibly be the best way to do this, right? I feel like I'm abusing numpy.where() to get around not knowing how to map values from multiple columns of a dataframe to a lambda function in a non-iterative way. (Also to avoid writing mildly gnarly lambda functions).

Kind of three questions, I guess.

1. Is it OK to nest numpy.where()s for triconditional array operations?
2. How can I non-iteratively map from two dataframe columns to one
   function?
3. If 2) is possible and 1) is acceptable, which is preferable?

Comment: Regarding the nesting, one alternative is to just use sequential `np.where()`s, much easier to read IMO.  Also, I think either @unutbu or @DSM showed a nice alternative to multiple `np.where()`s in the last month or so (using a different numpy function) but I can't seem to locate that now.

Comment: Btw, I think the way you did this is perfectly fine.  I imagine this is as efficient a way to do it as any, whether it is the most readable approach is somewhat a matter of preference.  I think this is one of those cases where the implicit vectorization of pandas makes it hard to code it in as readable a manner as if you were writing an explicit loop -- which, of course, you generally want to avoid in pandas.

Answer (score 6):

For your question about how to map multiple columns, you do it with

```
DataFrame.apply( , axis =1)
```

For your question I don't think you need this, but I think it's clearer if you do your calculation in a few steps:

```
df['low'] = df.A.map(lambda x: mydict[x][0])
df['high'] = df.A.map(lambda x: mydict[x][1])
df['error'] = np.maximum(df.B - df.high, 0) + np.minimum(df.B - df.low, 0)
df
     A    B  low  high  error
1  foo  1.2    1     2    0.0
2  bar  1.3    2     3   -0.7
3  foo  2.2    1     2    0.2
```

Comment: That third line is quite clever. I should've thought to take advantage of the fact that df.B will never be both (greater than the max for A) AND (less than the min for A). Like most "quite clever" code, it probably requires a comment to explain what exactly is going on, but... nicely done. +1

Answer (score 1):

I believe the code below is arguably more readable.

```
df['min'] = df.A.apply(lambda x: min(mydict[x]))
df['max'] = df.A.apply(lambda x: max(mydict[x]))
df['error'] = 0.
df.loc[df.B.gt(df['max']), 'error'] = df.B - df['max']
df.loc[df.B.lt(df['min']), 'error'] = df.B - df['min']
df.drop(['min', 'max'], axis=1, inplace=True)
>>> df
     A    B  error
1  foo  1.2    0.0
2  bar  1.3   -0.7
3  foo  2.2    0.2
```

I don't see why you couldn't use numpy.where() for triconditional array operations, but you do sacrifice simplicity.

Comment: just to note, you've clobbered df's `max` and `min` methods.

Comment: FYI methods don't get clobbered at all (except if you explicity assign to them), e.g. ``df.min = ....``. A set column is independent of this

Comment: hmm didn't know that... so does that mean that you always refer to your columns with the dict index notation rather than the method notation?

Comment: `df['max'] = ...` is fine and does not clobber a DataFrame's `max` function. `df.max = ...`, by contrast, would clobber the function.  You should always set with bracket notation.  It is safer to you brackets when referencing (to avoid this issue), but dot notation is pure convenience and works fine as long as you're not using one of the DataFrame's named properties or methods.

Comment: FWIW, it took me a while before I could figure out exactly what this was doing. Pretty sure this mostly has to do with my lack of familiarity with df.loc[row_indexer, column_indexer]. So, thanks for making me learn that. Now that I'm on board as far as loc is concerned, I agree this seems slightly more readable than maxymoo's answer. +1