# Handling assignment to empty selections from pandas.df.loc

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe, df. Let's say it looks something like this:

```
   A  B  C  
1  1  4  7
2  2  5  8
3  3  6  9
```

I want to add a new column, D, which is a function of columns B and C. *Which* function of columns B and C it is should depend on the value of column A. (This is somewhat related to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30793178/alternatives-to-nested-numpy-where-for-multiconditional-pandas-operations) of mine, but reading that is not necessary for answering this.)

For the purposes of this exercise, let's say that I want D to be B + C when A is less than 1.5, B * C when A is greater than 2.5, and 0 when A is between 1.5 and 2.5. The new dataframe should look like this:

```
   A  B  C  D
1  1  4  7  11
2  2  5  8  0
3  3  6  9  54
```

My solution is as follows:

```
df['D'] = 0.
df.loc[dtfr.A.lt(1.5), 'D'] = dtfr.B + dtfr.C
df.loc[dtfr.B.gt(2.5), 'D'] = dtfr.B * dtfr.C
```

Here's the problem. This function needs to run on about a thousand dataframes, each compiled from a single file in a large database of files. Sometimes - rarely, but sometimes - a dataframe will not contain a single value that returns "True" for the first statement in one of the df.loc[]s. For example, all of the values in one dataframe might be less than 2.5, as in this sample dataframe.

```
   A  B  C  
1  0  4  7
2  1  5  8
3  2  6  9
```

When I try to run the third line of my solution...

```
df.loc[dtfr.B.gt(2.5), 'D'] = dtfr.B * dtfr.C
```

...the shape of df.loc[dtfr.B.gt(2.5), 'D'] is (0,), which causes the assignment to throw a ValueError.

```
ValueError: array is not broadcastable to correct shape
```

Is there a way to handle this that's safer than a try/except for ValueError, which seems rather risky?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another way using numpy `select` [(documentation here)](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) that has pretty clean syntax:

```
df['D'] = np.select( [ df.A < 1.5,  df.A > 2.5  ],
                     [ df.B + df.C, df.B * df.C ], default=0 )

   A  B  C   D
1  1  4  7  11
2  2  5  8   0
3  3  6  9  54
```

It defaults to zero anyway, but I added that for completeness.  I'd like to give credit to either @DSM or @HappyLeapSecond (I think one of them?) for using this in an answer a couple of months ago but I'm unable to find that post now.

And also, here is an alternate syntax for @AmiTavory's answer FWIW.

```
df['D'] = 0
df.D = np.where( df.A < 1.5, df.B + df.C, df.D )
df.D = np.where( df.A > 2.5, df.B * df.C, df.D )
```

Answer (score 2):

> For the purposes of this exercise, let's say that I want D to be B + C when A is less than 1.5, B * C when A is greater than 2.5, and 0 when A is between 1.5 and 2.5

The following doesn't rely on the occurrence of rows which solve any of the specific conditions:

```
df['D'] = np.where(
    df.A < 1.5,
    df.B + dfC,
    np.where(
        df.A > 2.5,
        df.B * df.C,
        0))
```

Comment: Ha - nesting numpy.where()s was my first solution, way back when I asked the first question! You're right that it would solve this particular problem, but it's also pretty annoying to read. Good answer, but I'll wait and see if I get a more readable / elegant one before I accept.